# Using Context to get Identifier of a Drawable gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, drawable, android-context

This code may seem impractical, but I simplified it so I could better understand the answer.  I am getting a null pointer exception, and cannot figure out why.  I have president1.png in my drawable folder.  For "president1", I have also tried president1.png.  The method flipCard(View v) is being called by a button push with android:onClick="flipCard".  Any suggestions?

```
public void flipCard(View v){
card1.setImageResource(getIdentifier(getBaseContext()));
}


public static int getIdentifier(Context context){
return context.getResources().getIdentifier("president1", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

---

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/card8"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/card2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="flipCard"
    android:src="@drawable/facedown" />
```

Comment: Show the part where you call this method

Comment: It is a button click with android:onClick="flipCard" thru a couple of unusued methods. (I am using the View v where its called). ill update the code to make it clearer

Comment: Most likely the context you are passing to it is null. Actually, that's kind of the only way you're get an NPE here

Comment: I see. How do I make it not null?  Hours of research on Context, and it's still a giant confusion to me.  All of the resources just had it randomly appear without assigning it a value.  So I figured there was something to it that I did not understand where no value needed assigned.

Comment: As I said, post the code that calls this method, and preferably the surrounding Activity

Comment: The method is called by a Button being pushed.  In the button's .xml, I have used android:onClick=:"flipCard"  [I just double checked.]

Comment: I really can't help you until I see the code.

Comment: OK, I posted it above

Comment: Try replacing `getBaseContext()` with `v.getContext()`

Comment: I fixed an error elsewhere that stopped the null pointer (guess I shouldve been more thorough sharing the code like u said...sorry). Now nothing happens when I click as posted above or with v.getContext()

Comment: Success! the v.getContext() worked!  I had to drop the .png on my drawable name.  Please post the answer so I can give you the credit you deserve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
card1.setImageResource(getIdentifier(v.getContext()));
```

instead of

```
card1.setImageResource(getIdentifier(getBaseContext()));
```

This causes your code to use the Context the View is running in.

I'm fairly sure the problem was actually the `.png` in your filename, as any Context within your app would have access to the resources (unless your call to `getBaseContext()` was before the Activity context had been created, in which case it would return null).